# R: how to find cluster centroids with tsclust?

Tags: r, time-series, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a time-series dataset and I am required to find similar clusters in the data.

Based on my current knowledge and the requirements of my application, I used `SBD` measure (shape based distance) to calculate the dissimilarity matrix for my dataset and applied hierarchical clustering on it (using `tsclust`).
The R command used is:

```
library(dtwclust)    
hclust=tsclust(mydata,type="h", distance = "sbd")
```

I also used `cvi` for cluster validation (`cvi(hclust)`) and was able to get a value of 0.508 for Silhouette width (which I believe is good enough). The problem is that I don't know at which point to cut this cluster tree - for how many clusters (value of `k`) or at what height (value of `h`) to get the Silhouette width of 0.5?

Moreover, once I know this value of `k` or `h`, how do I find the centroids (time-series data) that represent these clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty straight-forward - thanks to Alexis who suggested me to read Appendix-A of the documentation, and @Haroon who suggested writing an email to Alexis. Here are the answers to my questions:

**1) How to identify the value of k or h for which the Silhouette value was 0.5?**

I ran a loop for different number of clusters and cut the dendrogram for these many clusters. Then, I computed the silhouette value for each of the cluster sets and identified the value for k where the value was 0.5. The code for this is:

```
library(dtwclust)
hclust=tsclust(mydata,type='h',distance='sbd')

#running the loop now
numberofclusters=c(2:100)
silValues=c(1:length(numberofclusters))    
for(size in numberofclusters){
  sbd_cluster=cutree(hclust,k=size)
  index=which(numberofclusters==size)
  x<-silhouette(sbd_cluster,dist=sbddist)
  silSBDclust[index]=mean(x[,3])
}
plot(clustersizes,silSBDclust,xlab="Number of clusters",ylab="Average silhouette width")
```

**2) How to identify cluster centroids?**
Once we have identified the number of clusters, we need to find the centroids for these clusters. Please note that the object returned by `tsclust()` is of type S4 (refer to the documentation of `TSClusters-Class`) and to access its formal elements, we need `@` operator unlike the `$` operator often used in R. When we know the value of `k` for our dendrogram, we can use this value in `tsclust()` again for better clustering.

```
hclust=tsclust(mydata,k=k,type='h',distance='sbd')
View(hclust@centroids)   #gives you a list of centroids
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: I tried this but I get "Error in View : trying to get slot "centroids" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots" Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a suggestion,
what is being done by BajajG can be done directly with `compare_clusterings`:

```
cfg <- compare_clusterings_configs(
  "h",
  k = 2L:100L,
  controls = list(
    hierarchical = hierarchical_control(method = "average", symmetric = TRUE)
  ),
  distances = pdc_configs("d", sbd = list())
)

evaluator <- cvi_evaluators("Sil")
comparison <- compare_clusterings(mydata, "h", cfg, 
                                  score.clus = evaluator$score,
                                  pick.clus = evaluator$pick)

best <- repeat_clustering(mydata, comparison, comparison$pick$config_id)
plot(best)
```

Check also the results in `comparison$results$hierarchical`.

EDIT: and also set `method = "all"` in `hierarchical_control` if you want to test other linkage methods.